# _Pragma not working

Tags: c

I am trying to use `#pragma` inside `#define`. I am doing something like this:

```
// I assume this is a correct syntax. Please point out if it is wrong
#define COVERAGE(x)  _Pragma (Coverage_tool #x)
```

And then inside the code I am using it as

```
COVERAGE(off) or COVERAGE(on).
```

Here on and off are strings.

But when I do this I get a compilation error saying  `"expected ) near off".`

I also tried `"off"`/`"on"` with quotes (regular strings.) But still same error.

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Well for one, you shouldn't ever use C++-style comments in a `#define` :)

Comment: It's #pragma not _Pragma - and you can't embed preprocessor directives in preprocessor directives.

Comment: @Erik you can embed _Pragma in a preprocessor directive.

Comment: @Erik: `_Pragma` can be used like `#pragma`, and it works in preprocessor macros. See §6.10.9.

Comment: Ahh ok, c99 - You can't use that in c89

Comment: Any idea how to get it working on VC2010 which partially supports C99.

Answer (score 7):

I think that strictly speaking, [Lindydancer's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587655/pragma-not-working/5587695#5587695) needs to be of the form:

```
#define COVERAGE(x) PRAGMA(Coverage_tool x)
#define PRAGMA(x) _Pragma(#x)
```

This is the form the standard uses in an example, and it needs to be this way because `_Pragma` operator processing occurs in a translation phase before string literal concatenation. `_Pragma` is defined in such a way that it'll only deal with stripping off the leading and trailing quotes when manufacturing the corresponding `#pragma` - not any other ones that are from 'concatenated' literals.

However, your compiler might be tolerant of the other approach (GCC isn't).

Note: if the `#pragma Coverage_tool` pragma needs quotes around the `on`/`off` operand, then the `COVERAGE` macro needs to be:

```
#define COVERAGE(x) PRAGMA(Coverage_tool #x)
```

Note #2:  If you're using Microsoft C, I think you want:

```
#define COVERAGE(x) PRAGMA(Coverage_tool x)
#define PRAGMA(x) __pragma(x)
```

because Microsoft's directive is spelled slightly differently and, more annoyingly, *doesn't* want quotes surrounding the argument to the operator.

But `Coverage_tool` isn't a documented pragma supported by MSVC, so I think there's still some important information missing.

Since you have some code coverage tool outside of the compiler that's processing this pragma, I think you'll need to hide it from the compiler.  The tool will probably define some macro name that it recognizes when it's processing that won't be defined when the compiler is doing its work. For example, lint will define the macro `lint` when it's processing and Microsoft's resource compiler will define `RC_INVOKED`.

Let's assume that your code coverage tool defines `COVERAGE_TOOL` when it's running. You might make both tools happy with something like:

```
#if COVERAGE_TOOL
#define COVERAGE(x) PRAGMA(Coverage_tool x)
#define PRAGMA(x) _Pragma(#x)
#else
#define COVERAGE(x)
#endif
```

But I'm just guessing.  I would expect that the docs for the coverage tool would be quite explicit about how these directives need to be integrated into your code if it supports MSVC - you should look there for details (or ask the vendor).

Comment: You might very well be right, I'll check it tomorrow when I have access to real tools.

Comment: My environment is VC2005. (visual studion 2005). Do you know if they use _Pragma. Even after string literals error did not disappear. But when I tried __pragma it disappeared. But I still get an error saying unknown pragma.

Comment: @agent smith: as far as I know, MSVC doesn't support a `Coverage_tool` pragma.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805.aspx for the pragmas MSVC supports.  Who/what is suggesting you to use `Coverage_tool`?

Comment: oh that is a not a pragma supported by VC. I am adding a tool which instruments source code. They support this pragma.

Comment: @agent smith: see my edit which might help - but I think you'll need to refer to the coverage tool's docs or support.

Comment: @Michael: thanks!!! Do u know if VC2010 supports _Pragma. VC2005 does not support it. If I am not wrong then VC2010 supports some form of _Pragma.

Comment: @agent: as far as I know no version of MSVC supports `_Pragma`; only the similar `__pragma`.  VS2010 definitely supports `__pragma` - I believe that started in VS2008.

Comment: @Michaer Barr: As my answer was incorrect, I deleted it. One can't rely on string concatenation for the argument of `_Pragma` (something that I should have know, as I've been working with similar things before). Thanks for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio 2005, the `__pragma` keyword is undocumented.  It is documented and available in Visual Studio 2008.  Note that you need two underscore characters and it's all lowercase.

[Pragma Directives and the __Pragma Keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805%28VS.90%29.aspx)